# Copy a subarray inside an array based on it's values using ruby on rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have an array of arrays like this:

```
array = [[1, 'Something', '123456321'], [2, 'Something, Something', '123456321, 1234563212']]
```

I want to loop the subarrays and if the second element of each array contains the comma I want to split that element by comma and then make a copy of that subarray in the array but with single values without comma. So I want to get this result:

```
array = [[1, 'Something', '123456321'], [2, 'Something', '123456321'], [2, 'Something', 1234563212']]
```

I want to note that if the second element of array it's made of two or more elements like this *'Something, Something'* then the third element will automatically have the same structure *'123456321, 1234563212'*. So my question is if it is possible to do something like this using ruby on rails?
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
array.flat_map do |id, names, values|
  parsed_names  = names.split(', ')
  parsed_values = values.split(', ')

  parsed_names.zip(parsed_values).map { |name, value| [id, name, value] }
end
```

Comment: To be on the safe side, maybe `split(/\s*,\s*/)`.

Comment: Can you also help me to reverse this?
From `array = [[1, 'Something', '123456321'], [2, 'Something', '123456321'], [2, 'Something', 1234563212']]` to `array = [[1, 'Something', '123456321'], [2, 'Something, Something', '123456321, 1234563212']]`

Comment: @Lucasio, could you open a new question. The answer is long and different enough that I wouldn't be able to write it as a comment in a comprehensive way.